# Php, I need delete spesific text in array and later i need prepend it

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

if size inside index contains 'round' i need delete that index and prepend it of array. Because round size should come first. I tried foreach loop and array_search the data later unset it but doesnt work. Data have array inside object. Function, inside a controller and is using a model for fetch data.

```
public function getDesignSize()
{
    $design =  $this->input->post('design', true);
    $quality =  $this->input->post('quality', true);
    $currentSizeData = $this->products_model->getAllPropDataForProductSize('sku_list', 
    array('size', 'url', 'color'), array('quality' => $quality, 'design' => $design, 'url is 
    NOT NULL' => NULL), array('size,color', 'asc'));
    $currentSizeArray = array();
}
```

Data output look like this:

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 060x090 1/5
        [url] => floki-861-50-lilac-20991
        [color] => 50-Lilac
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 080x150
        [url] => floki-861-50-lilac-20992
        [color] => 50-Lilac
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 080x150
        [url] => floki-861-60-white-20134
        [color] => 60-White
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 080x150
        [url] => floki-861-70-beige-20140
        [color] => 70-Beige
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 080x150
        [url] => floki-861-95-silver-21002
        [color] => 95-Silver
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 080x150
        [url] => floki-861-99-anthracite-20146
        [color] => 99-Anthracite
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 120x120 round
        [url] => floki-861-50-lilac-20993
        [color] => 50-Lilac
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [size] => 120x120 round
        [url] => floki-861-60-white-20138
        [color] => 60-White
    )
)
```

I tried this and i can delete it:

```
   foreach ($currentSizeData as $sizeData) {
        if (preg_match("/(round)/", $sizeData->size)) {
            unset($currentSizeData[$currentSizeArrayCount]);
        }
        $currentSizeArrayCount++;
    }
```

I need to prepend the deleted index. I need to add in the same format.

Comment: and what had you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to iterate over all of the dataset.

However there are two solutions. the first is to unset the array elements that has a specific condition then unshift these elements to the main array :

```
foreach ($currentSizeData as $key => $ar) {
    if (strpos($ar->size, 'round') !== false) {
        $shift[] = $ar;
        unset($currentSizeData[$key]);
    }
}

array_unshift($currentSizeData, ...$shift);
```

the other way is by using `usort`

```
usort($currentSizeData, function ($a, $b) {
    return strpos($a->size, 'round') === false;
});
```

Comment: ty for your help. First solution look like works for me just different format but when i loop the 'shift' inside a foreach its give me same format. thank you so much